# How do you grab the root Windows directory of the computer running your code? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

As mentioned above, just checking if there is a method to check the root letter (ie. `C:\\` or `S:\\`) of the computer that your program is running on.

I don't know if there's a method for this inbuilt into `os`, or if I need a specialist function.

Comment: Use OS module to get the current working directory (`getcwd()`) , then parse that for just the start, I think that is your best bet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **On Windows Try This:**

**First way ( with ctypes and pathlib modules )**

```
import ctypes.wintypes, pathlib
CSIDL_PERSONAL = 5
SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0

buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)
my_path = pathlib.Path(buf.value)
print(my_path.drive)
```

**Another Way ( with win32 package ):**

```
import win32api
print(win32api.GetWindowsDirectory())
```

**Third Way ( with win32 package ):**

```
import win32com.client
objShell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
allUserDocs = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
print(allUserDocs)
```

**Fourth Way ( with os Module ) :**

```
import os
print(os.path.expandvars("%SystemRoot%"))
```

**Fifth Way ( with wmi Module ) :**

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print(os.SystemDrive)
```

> **ON Windows and LINUX:**

**First Way ( with os and pathlib modules ) :**

```
import os, pathlib
home = pathlib.Path(os.path.expanduser("~"))
print(home.drive)
```

**Second Way ( with pathlib module ):**

```
import pathlib
my_path = pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path.home())
print(my_path.drive)
```

Good Luck ...

Comment: @James Farrow This is exactly what you are looking for. Particularly **Fourth Way ( with os Module )**

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
import os    
    def root_path():
        return os.path.abspath(os.sep) 
root_path()
```

it gives '/' for linux
and C:\ for windows

Answer (score 0):

Note that WiLL_K's method is better, I didn't know that this method existed.

```
import os
letter = os.getcwd().split("\\")[0][0]
```

If the script is executed from the `C:` drive, `letter` will contain `C`.

Answer (score 0):

**[Note: I am using Python 3.6.3 and Windows 8.1 x64]**

**

> os.path.abspath gives the root directory and os.sep gives the
>   character used by the operating system to separate pathname components
>   which is '\' for Windows. To remove the double slashes I used the
>   os.path.normpath() function

**

```
import os

def getRootDirectory():
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(os.sep))

print(getRootDirectory())
```

Which outputs:

```
C:\
```